Error in sql trigger: You have an error in your SQL syntax
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateBalance
AFTER INSERT ON Transactions
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.TransactionType = 'Deposit' THEN
        UPDATE Accounts
        SET Balance = Balance + NEW.Amount
        WHERE AccountID = NEW.AccountID;
    ELSEIF NEW.TransactionType = 'Withdrawal' THEN
        UPDATE Accounts
        SET Balance = Balance - NEW.Amount
        WHERE AccountID = NEW.AccountID;
    END IF;
END;

In this code I am getting the following error

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8


Make sure you use DELIMITER before defining the trigger.
